# Prove associative property

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory, binary-operations, associativity

Given:
$\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ with the following operation $\circ$
$(a_1,b_1)\circ (a_2,b_2):=(a_1\cdot b_2+a_2,b_1\cdot b_2)$
I need to prove the associative property. So:
$\bigl((a_1,b_1)\circ (a_2,b_2)\bigl)\circ (a_3,b_3)=(a_1,b_1)\circ \bigl((a_2,b_2)\circ (a_3,b_3)\bigl)$
My problem is, I am not sure how to get from $((a_1\cdot b_2+a_2)\cdot b_3+a_3,(b_1\cdot b_2)\cdot b_3)$ to $(a_1\cdot(a_2\cdot b_3+a_3),b_1\cdot(b_2\cdot b_3))$, except for the second part which is trivial $(b_1\cdot b_2)\cdot b_3=b_1\cdot(b_2\cdot b_3)$.

Comment: $\bigl((a_1,b_1)\circ \bigl((a_2,b_2)\circ (a_3,b_3)\bigl) \ne (a_1\cdot(a_2\cdot b_3+a_3),b_1\cdot(b_2\cdot b_3))$. $\bigl((a_1,b_1)\circ \bigl((a_2,b_2)\circ (a_3,b_3)\bigl) =(a_1b_2b_3 + a_2*b3 + a_3, b_1b_2b_3)$.  So you need to show $(a_1b_2 +a_2)b_3 + a_3=a_1b_2b_3 + a_2*b3 + a_3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it.

$((a,b)\circ (c,d))\circ(e,f) = (ad+c,bd)\circ(e,f) = ((ad+c)f+e,bdf) = (adf+cf + e, bdf)$.

$(a,b)\circ((c,d)\circ(e,f)) = (a,b)\circ(cf+e,df)=(adf+cf+e, bdf)$

Comment: I see know, really stupid of me, didn't expand it correctly in the second case. Sorry for asking such questions.

Comment: 'okay.  Your mistake was $((a_1\cdot b_2+a_2)\cdot b_3+a_3,(b_1\cdot b_2)\cdot b_3)$ should have be  $(a_1(b_2*b_3) + (a_2*b_3 + a_3), (b_1*b_2)*b_3)$.